# Add folders to specific compression archives

Tags: linux

SOURCE="/opt/gitlab/full

BACKUP_CONFIG="/etc/gitlab"

I have folder $SOURCE/ **$date.tar**

I want to add $BACKUP_CONFIG to $SOURCE/ **$date.tar**

Since this folder will generate **$date.tar** a weekly

How can i add $BACKUP_CONFIG to $SOURCE/**$date.tar**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can append files to tar archive, from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/appending-files.html):

```
tar --append --file=$SOURCE/$date.tar $BACKUP_CONFIG
```

You can replace the file in a tar archive, by deleting and append a file, from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_32.html):

```
tar --delete --file=$SOURCE/$date.tar $BACKUP_CONFIG
tar --append --file=$SOURCE/$date.tar $BACKUP_CONFIG
```